# How do I move a custom simulator rule definition

Tags: ocean

It appears that the DLL, version and namespace of a custom simulator rule are encoded into the development stategy within the .ptd.

I would like to move the code etc for a custom rule into a new namespace/DLL.

We deal with this for custom domain object style using serialisation binding code. Is it possible to do the same for custom simulator rules?

Cheers,

Neal

Comment: I suspect we have the same issue with custom worksteps. Petrel ignores the assembly version, but the lock-in to a fixed assembly name, namespace and class name is a major pain.

Comment: By the way, custom serialization bindings only apply to binary serialization (but Petrel only calls the binders for some objects, like custom domain objects and their contents), not IIdentifiables using e.g. XML serialization via a IDataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for Robert:

Petrel 2012 has a new attribute for the worksteps and processes: you need to implement the UniqueIdCore method to provide a globally (across all projects) unique ID that is fixed and stable in the form of a Guid. This UniqueId will be serialized into the Petrel projects; it is used in serialized workflows. Prior to 2012 release, a serialized workflow would be broken if you changed the assembly or namespace of the workstep. If you later want to change the workstep type, you can do so without breaking serialized workflows as long as you provide the same unique identifier.

Answer for Neal:

Regarding the conversation with colleagues, it is an arg pack softened identity string issue, so unfortunately that means that you cannot move it to a different assembly or even change the class name.
There is only one semi-work around can be possible now (didn't check it): leave the arg packs in the old assembly / class name and move everything else, but of course this is not a good solution.